# Remove hide column option in each column header of angular slickgrid

Tags: angular, slickgrid

In angular slickgrid having a provision to hide individual column over the column header. While continuously hiding all columns by this option, entire slickgrid column views removed. So i want to disappear **Hide column** option against the each column.

Fig 1: Reference for Hide column option in each column header

[image: Hide column option in each column menu]

Fig 2: Entire slickgrid column views removed

[image: Empty slickgrid view after hiding all columns by column menu]

Comment: You have to use the `gridOptions` input and set `headerMenu.hideColumnHideCommand` to `true`

Comment: Thank you, working fine

Comment: @PoulKruijt has the correct answer to hide the option, thanks for replying. However I want to point out that Angular-Slickgrid keeps a reference internally to the visible/hidden columns and if you (as a user) ever modify the list of columns via the grid `setColumns()` method with Angular-Slickgrid knowing about it, then you end up with such behavior. So I'm just adding this as reference if that helps in finding your issue. I assume you must have done some changes to that example because it works fine on the [GitHub Demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/formatter) page.

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks for your explanation, although I do see on the demo page you link, that if you hide all columns, you are left with an empty table as shown in the screenshot in the question, and there is no way out of it. I believe that's the issue the OP is talking about

Comment: it works as expected on my side... I tested on all browsers (Chrome, Firefox) and it works as expected (even tested on IE11)

Comment: @ghiscoding Please share the video clip of the discussed thing from your side. In our side, views will be empty. Please shown yours as video clip. It may be halpful for us.